# How to return footer to its place?

Tags: footer, sticky-footer

I have my site: [site](http://104.131.21.171). It is looking good in Chrome and Edge. But if you use Firefox or IE, the footer moves to the right. How I can to move it back?

Comment: for footer put left:0 in the css

Comment: you have given position absolute ... just give it left:0

Comment: Thank you so much! It works, amazing!